# how to fill asp.net hidden field with Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, hidden-field

im trying this format:

```
$("#<%= hfWidth.UniqueID %>").val($("#drag").attr("offsetWidth"));
```

to fill the hidden field with client-side values

but when I do postback, the values doesn't seem to be saved.

help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it with `<%= hfWidth.ClientID %>`

Comment: This is only possible after 2 days.

Comment: yep.. im stuck with this for 2days... who ever made that stupid rule?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get params from  the server side, you should use name instead of id attribute.

And your code should work :

```
$("#elementId").val("value");
```

Comment: the .UniqueID is the value set to the name attribute of the object.

Comment: Can you provide us more code than that ? Because this code doesn't show sufficient info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_checkbox" runat="server" />
```

in your Javascript:

```
           function somefunction() {

                $("#<%= hdn_checkbox.ClientID %>").val("test");

            }

            $('.btnGreen').click(function () {

                somefunction();
                alert($("#<%= hdn_checkbox.ClientID %>").val());
                return true;
            });
```